# How to make Javascript to work for all the browsers

Tags: javascript

I come from desktop application background and now I am working on web based application. So I am fairly new to client side script like Javascript.
 I have a question that what set of standards we need to follow to make sure that our Java script code will work.

Any link for the same will be really helpfull.

Comment: your question is unclear. Every browser supports JavaScript natively. Do you have a specific piece of javascript code you want to know if it will work across all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what browsers you want to support. If you want to support pretty much everything, use the ECMAscript 3 standard. If you just want to support relatively recent browsers, you can use the ECMAscript 5 standard. Any features other than that and you can use [this](http://caniuse.com/) site to see about compatibility.

EDIT: For any other functionality that you think might not be very widespread, you can always check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) as well.